# ROS: catkin_make vs. catkin build

Tags: ros

When using ROS:

Why should I use `catkin build` from catkin_tools instead of `catkin_make`?

I've been told that `catkin build` is better but no one who tells me this can give me a reason why.

Comment: Their documentation describes the difference:  https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The main difference is the isolated environment that you get with `catkin build`. This makes the whole build configuration much more compartmentalized and robust to changes in the configuration (add/remove package, modify a cmake variable etc.)

Apart from that you also get much better and easily-readable colored cmdline output which makes the whole experience much more pleasant.

@SteveO's link also gives a nice summary of the changes between the tools.

Adding to `catkin build` you also get many other useful subcommands with `catkin` including `catkin clean` for cleaning the `build`, `devel` and `install` spaces, as well as `catkin list` , `catkin locate`, `catkin profile`

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the isolated build, it is much more convenient to use:

- Independent packages are build in parallel which can make it much faster.
- `catkin build` can be used from any directory in the workspace while `catkin_make` only works in the top level directory.
- It is easy to only build a single package (+ dependencies): `catkin build package_name` or, when called from the package directory, `catkin build --this`.  Add `--no-deps` to skip dependencies.
  (Note that `catkin_make` has a  `--only-pkg-with-deps` flag for this, but there it will result in a persistent setting so next call of just `catkin_make` would also only build this package which is very unintuitive.)
- `catkin clean` makes it easy to wipe build/devel without having to use a scary `rm -rf`.
- Some other useful commands (list, locate, ...) as already mentioned by @bergercookie.