# Sourcing catkin workspace populates ROS_PACKAGE_PATH with individual package paths

Tags: ros

When creating a new catkin workspace, building it and then sourcing `devel/setup.sh`, the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is populated with paths from individual packages instead of only the root directory that contains all the packages. The packages are still found when calling `roslaunch` and all works fine, but my understanding is that `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` should only contain the root directory. For example, I create a new catkin workspace:

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH # prints /opt/ros/melodic/share
mkdir -p $HOME/test_ws/src
cd $HOME/test_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
#copy / create packages pkg1, pkg2, ...
cd $HOME/test_ws
catkin build
source devel/setup.bash
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH # at this point, i would expect 
#$HOME/test_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share, instead i get
#$HOME/test_ws/src/pkg1:$HOME/test_ws/src/pkg2:/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

Is this the normal behavior or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the expected behavior of `catkin build` as stated on the  [Migrating from catkin_make](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/ros-catkin-make-vs-catkin-build) website:

*It generates .catkin files where **each source package is listed, individually, instead of just listing the source space for the workspace**. This leads to similar ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variables which list each package source space.*

If using the `catkin_make`, however, it does add only the root/source path of the workspace, as i expected initially.